# Most general Fock state of spin-1/2 fermions: a parametrization

Tags: hilbert-space, many-body, second-quantization

I wanted to ask if it is true that a valid parametrization of a generic (unnormalized) state in the Fock space of spin-$1/2$ fermions can be written as:
$$|\psi>= \prod_{j=1}^L[\alpha_j +\beta_j \hat c^{+}_{j,-}+\gamma_j \hat c^{+}_{j,+}+\delta_j \hat c^+_{j,-}\hat c^+_{j,+}]|0>,$$ where I have introduced the fermionic creation operators at site $j$ with spin $\sigma=\pm$, and the terms multiplying them are arbitrary coefficients. I believe it is not, since it captures only product states. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: @Mauricio I think it is needed in order to include the states with double occupancy on the same site (with opposite spins).

Comment: @Mauricio the OP is correct. A spin half orbital can be unfilled, spin up, spin down, or filled both spin up and down, and then no more.